# memcached invalidation based on values

Tags: memcached, invalidation, key-value-store

Is it possible to invalidate `memcahced` entries based on values.
In my app, I am assigning user in different groups and I store this mapping in `memcached`.

```
key = userID
value = groupID
```

So multiple `userIds` map to one `groupID`.

When I delete a particular group then I want to remove all entries in `memcache` store which have value as the `groupID` of the deleted group.
So Essentially I want to delete the entries having particular values. How do I do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get key's by value in memcached. What you could do though is have a key called groupID that has a comma separated userID's. If you want to see who is part of a group then you could get the key called groupID and parse  out the userID's. Then if you have a key for each userID you could delete them with the parsed userID's. You could use memcached's append function too to just append the userID's to a groupID key when a new user registers for you system.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a [blog post on maintaining a set](http://dustin.github.com/2011/02/17/memcached-set.html) a while back that may do what you're looking for.

It's essentially what mikewied is suggesting, but with more words and code samples.